# Why do these pods have status "Init:0/2"

Tags: kubernetes

I ran the command "helm upgrade" in order to apply the changes I made to the config.yaml file. However, now I have two pods that are in the state of Init:0/2 and a recurrent FailedCreatePodSandBox error in them. Any suggestions on what to do next?

kubectl get pods:

```
NAME                            READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
continuous-image-puller-2hhv4   1/1     Running       0          30h
continuous-image-puller-2qh7z   0/1     Init:0/2      0          30h
hook-image-awaiter-gg7n8        1/1     Running       0          17s
hook-image-puller-sz8qf         0/1     Init:0/2      0          18s
hook-image-puller-xnc65         1/1     Running       0          18s
hub-567bb6bc68-g5lcs            1/1     Running       0          30h
ngshare-586b877ff5-wg8sq        0/1     Terminating   0          86d
ngshare-85c7799db8-gw6hq        1/1     Running       0          35d
proxy-65d966d5b6-cz2rg          1/1     Running       0          30h
```

kubectl describe pods (for continuous-image-puller-2qh7z):

```
Name:           continuous-image-puller-2qh7z
Namespace:      staging-jhub
Priority:       0
Node:           star11/172.27.188.111
Start Time:     Mon, 05 Jun 2023 17:03:51 -0700
Labels:         app=jupyterhub
                component=continuous-image-puller
                controller-revision-hash=84bfb4599d
                pod-template-generation=4
                release=staging-jhub
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/continuous-image-puller
Init Containers:
  image-pull-metadata-block:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         jupyterhub/k8s-network-tools:2.0.1-0.dev.git.5866.h7de20b77
    Image ID:      
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -c
      echo "Pulling complete"
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:         <none>
  image-pull-singleuser:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         libretextsregistry.ddns.net/binder-dev-libretexts-2ddefault-2denv-1cb626:4895042a71a713052ffbf05a0fe907098bf368ab
    Image ID:      
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -c
      echo "Pulling complete"
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:         <none>
Containers:
  pause:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          registry.k8s.io/pause:3.9
    Image ID:       
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:         <none>
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:            <none>
QoS Class:          BestEffort
Node-Selectors:     <none>
Tolerations:        hub.jupyter.org/dedicated=user:NoSchedule
                    hub.jupyter.org_dedicated=user:NoSchedule
                    node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                    node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                    node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists
                    node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                    node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists
                    node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule op=Exists
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------                  ----                    ----     -------
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m10s (x8443 over 30h)  kubelet  (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "563235750ab2900720f155529383e7e8c6e36af111d850ddbefa76b5ad60dfa3": Multus: [staging-jhub/continuous-image-puller-2qh7z]: error getting pod: Unauthorized
```

kubectl describe pods (for hook-image-puller-sz8qf):

```
Name:           hook-image-puller-sz8qf
Namespace:      staging-jhub
Priority:       0
Node:           star11/172.27.188.111
Start Time:     Tue, 06 Jun 2023 23:43:02 -0700
Labels:         app=jupyterhub
                component=hook-image-puller
                controller-revision-hash=b8b77fc77
                pod-template-generation=1
                release=staging-jhub
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/hook-image-puller
Init Containers:
  image-pull-metadata-block:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         jupyterhub/k8s-network-tools:2.0.0
    Image ID:      
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -c
      echo "Pulling complete"
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:         <none>
  image-pull-singleuser:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         libretextsregistry.ddns.net/binder-dev-libretexts-2ddefault-2denv-1cb626:230d85d708cb6f6d1b6ba36bd2919a431eede445
    Image ID:      
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -c
      echo "Pulling complete"
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:         <none>
Containers:
  pause:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.8
    Image ID:       
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:         <none>
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:            <none>
QoS Class:          BestEffort
Node-Selectors:     <none>
Tolerations:        hub.jupyter.org/dedicated=user:NoSchedule
                    hub.jupyter.org_dedicated=user:NoSchedule
                    node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                    node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                    node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists
                    node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                    node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists
                    node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule op=Exists
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               5m2s                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned staging-jhub/hook-image-puller-sz8qf to star11
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  5m2s                 kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "480a19ef1acceddd4ac6397ce662b089f1ff7234cdc20cc3a24f3667125b7779": Multus: [staging-jhub/hook-image-puller-sz8qf]: error getting pod: Unauthorized
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  4m48s                kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "d2e751acddb353b5d819eb02f58169684f2300f3a25dc86d788a5338ff915c21": Multus: [staging-jhub/hook-image-puller-sz8qf]: error getting pod: Unauthorized
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  4m37s                kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "d3a7e3b0d2a33d97fe80bf1bd24564f10d8d6cf522ec5675de6b49a9c295be7b": Multus: [staging-jhub/hook-image-puller-sz8qf]: error getting pod: Unauthorized
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  4m22s                kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "7b208eea6c900d2af63e003e62094bf2b918d1f8d317d98ff9eb9dd763d119ad": Multus: [staging-jhub/hook-image-puller-sz8qf]: error getting pod: Unauthorized
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  4m10s                kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "0d4088512fa8fe86bf73b921d3d4b35ead6b1389a1b2c86ba9fd0c6bf261d62d": Multus: [staging-jhub/hook-image-puller-sz8qf]: error getting pod: Unauthorized
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  3m59s                kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "2de035d394b5d5d51215262c95ff584b4c133db42f30ec9c7fb43b64a8ab6ac3": Multus: [staging-jhub/hook-image-puller-sz8qf]: error getting pod: Unauthorized
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  3m44s                kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "606274f002f03a444b7549ccb85e61a64017aebf649605994bed0cf15f84e518": Multus: [staging-jhub/hook-image-puller-sz8qf]: error getting pod: Unauthorized
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  3m31s                kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "d60db7015325f37f1fcfa6438845515786e49d9d599f6640dba5b8a1d3bc407d": Multus: [staging-jhub/hook-image-puller-sz8qf]: error getting pod: Unauthorized
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  3m18s                kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "cd70873b3b424c659093b9f948fa0717b9680d5935bfbb555e2ef194243b0830": Multus: [staging-jhub/hook-image-puller-sz8qf]: error getting pod: Unauthorized
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  11s (x14 over 3m4s)  kubelet            (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "d404a995dc32e2780533c0ce0afc1f8e5681f8ddfaca289c082b088da9e72728": Multus: [staging-jhub/hook-image-puller-sz8qf]: error getting pod: Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the `kubectl describe pods` command the pod has two init containers. Those init containers run in a consecutive order, meaning the second only starts when the first finished.

The main containers will only start after all init containers have run successfully. To indicate that the pod first has the status `Init:0/2`, meaning 0 of 2 init containers finished.

After the first init container ran it will go into `Init:1/2`. But you might never see that depending on how long those init containers take to fulfill their task.